# How to play audio in player?

Tags: jquery

I use this player: https://b-jams.netlify.com/album.html

I have to click on any music.

But I want to play the music player by clicking the button

After click on play show this error in console:

> album.js:301 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPaused' of
>   null

How to issue this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`album.js`](https://b-jams.netlify.com/scripts/album.js) file.

If you click on the 'Play' button, it will call the `togglePlayFromPlayerBar` function (lines 296-320), which contains the following statement (line 320):

```
if (currentSoundFile.isPaused() && event.target.className === "ion-play") {
```

The `currentSoundFile` variable is set inside the `setSong` function (lines 1-14), which is called when you click on a song in the list; so, if you click on the 'Play' button before selecting a song, this variable might be `null` (it ) and the following error will be raised:

> Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot read property `isPaused` of `null`

A simple way to avoid this error could be to check the `currentSoundFile` variable before calling its `isPaused` function, *i.e.*:

```
if (currentSoundFile && currentSoundFile.isPaused() && event.target.className === "ion-play") {
```

**Update:**

You asked:

> Thank you, I add `if (currentSoundFile && currentSoundFile.isPaused() && event.target.className === "ion-play") {` but don't play song after click play button before selecting a song,

If you want to reproduce the 1st song of the list when `currentSoundFile` is `null` and you click on the 'Play' button, you could simply call `setSong`, *i.e.*:

```
if (!currentSoundFile) {
  setSong(1);
}
if (currentSoundFile.isPaused() && event.target.className === "ion-play") {
```

Comment: Thank you, I add `if (currentSoundFile && currentSoundFile.isPaused() && event.target.className === "ion-play") {` but don't play song after click play button before selecting a song,

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you :-)